# Does tcp/ip protocol explained when connection will time out or be refused?

Tags: tcp, connection, timeout, protocols

While a tcp client is connecting to a tcp server, and at same time the Listening port at server side hasn't been established. At this time will the tcp client report connection refused exception or connection time out exception ?

At first I think a connection refused exception will be reported by tcp/ip, because the server could check if the LISTEN port( which is connected by client) is exist. But actually a connection time out instead.

I am wondering if tcp/ip protocol has explained such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

> At this time will the tcp client report connection refused exception or connection time out exception ?

If the client gets an active refusal, i.e. a TCP RST segment, this shows up at the client as `ECONN.` Otherwise you get a connection timeout. Note that this can also include the case where an intermediate firewall prevented the connection, as it is usually considered more secure not to leak the information that the host even exists if firewall rules prevent connecting to that port.